# Breakpoint in Silverlight 5 not working

Tags: silverlight-5.0

```
           **SILVERLIGHT**
```

The breakpoint feature is not working in silverlight 5.Please tell me what's the issue and how to resolve the Issue.

```
     **XAML DESIGN**

     <UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

        <!--<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Width="200" Height="200" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Background="Azure" MouseLeftButtonDown="Border_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="lstClickReport" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" Width="300" Height="200"/>-->
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Message}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>




    Please do the needful.
```

Comment: @Zee wrong, with Silverlight 5. Breaking and debugging data bindings was a key new feature.

Comment: @jv42 i apologize, thanks for correcting my mistake, previous post was deleted since it was not true

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the Output window and see if the module has been built. Sometimes, you might have accidentally turned it off in the ConfigurationManager.

Furthermore, internet explorer caching has been also responsible for holding on to old copies of DLLs, especially if you are running with Assembly Library Caching.

Answer (score -2):

As described in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg181270%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), XAML is a markup language, some of the typical strategies for debugging within Visual Studio are not available.

For example, there is no way to set a breakpoint within a XAML file. This topic describes how XAML works in the Silverlight architecture while in a debugging context, and provides some strategies for eliminating problems in Silverlight XAML during the design and development phase. That's why you can not setup the breakpoint in your XAML.

[EDIT 08/28/2012]

I did not know that XAML debugging is added into SL5 so after @jv42 suggested XAML debugging is working in SL5, I decided to give a quick try. What i found is that XAML allows breakpoint setting to Binding syntax only within any XAML element means the property must have a binding to it to for being enabled to debug.

BP will not hit:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Red">
  <TextBlock Text="Hello World"/>
</Grid>
```

BP Will hit:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Red">
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding ****}"/>
</Grid>
```

Once Binding is properly configured you can see the BP hit and BindingState is populated in Local.

In above case I think the BP did not hit because in {Binding Message} the Message part is not properly configured. It would be good to know the code behind the "Message" and how this property is set. Unless binding is set properly the BP will not hit the XAML.

Comment: Since Silverlight 5, you can debug Data Binding by setting breakpoints in XAML.